# Why '\0' ends the input of read()?

Tags: c

The following code demonstrates that if there is `\0` in the input, the input is not read after it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  int fd;
  int fd2;
  char buf[200];
  int n;
  char fname[] = "/tmp/tst-perror.XXXXXX";
  fd = mkstemp (fname);
  fd2 = dup (fd);
  write(fd2, "a", 2); // \0 is written out
  write(fd2, "b", 1);
  write(fd2, "\n", 1);
  close (fd2);
  lseek (fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  n = read (fd, buf, sizeof (buf));
  printf("%.*s", (int) n, buf);
  close (fd);
  unlink (fname);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is `a`.

If we use `1` instead of `2` in the first `write()`, the output is `ab`. Is it proper behavior? I did not find anything about it in read(2).

Comment: This is how c-strings work. Otherwise, your `printf` wouldn't know where the string ends.

Comment: A better test is to fill the buffer with some character, e.g. `'x'`, then `read`, and print the contents of the buffer as hex numbers in a loop: `for (int i=0;i<20;i++) printf("%02x\n", buf[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` is read *after* the `\0` byte. However, `%s` `printf` format specifier expects a `\0`-terminated string.

Instead of `printf` try `write`ing `n` bytes to `STDOUT_FILENO` or 1:

```
write(1, buf, n);
```